# How to delete every second line from RichDataTextBox?

Tags: c#, richtextbox

How to delete number of lines from richDataTextBox? I need to delete each second line.
For example, I have a text document, opened in rich DataTextBox..

```
1. "aaaaaaa  
     bbbbbbb  
     ccccccc  
     ddddddd"
```

How can I delete lines: `"bbbbbbb"` and `"ddddddd"`... and continue till the end of the text file.

```
var lines = this.dataTextBox.Lines;
```

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329347/delete-a-specific-line-in-a-net-richtextbox....may help

Comment: This link is good... I saved that code for future problems. Thank You!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use LINQ to delete every second line:

```
var lines=richTextBox1.Lines
    . Where((l, index) => index % 2 == 0)
    .Select((l, index) => l);
richTextBox1.Lines = lines.ToArray();
```

It selects all lines that should **not** be deleted and skips all others.

Comment: Thank You very much. Exactly, what I need. (I'm still not strong in syntax.) I like to use LINQ. It is perfect for me!