# dynamically change text decorations on multiple spans/regions in a wpf textblock

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vb.net, textblock

I am trying to design an app that strikes out certain characters on a string if another 1 or 2 strings are contained within that string.

So far I can seem to get the leading sub string to do its thing fairly reliably, but the second sub-string always seems to produce unpredictable results, can anyone help? (c# or vb is fine)

A screen snip example of it working for the main (1st) filter, but not the sub (2nd):
[image]

Heres the code:

```
Public Function FormatFilteredName(mainFilter As String, subFilter As String) As TextBlock
    Dim tbNew As New TextBlock(New Run(FullFileName))
    tbNew.Text = FullFileName
    tbNew.FontSize = FONT_SIZE
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(FullFileName) Then
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(mainFilter) Then
            GetFilterSpan(mainFilter, tbNew)
        End If
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(subFilter) Then
            GetFilterSpan(subFilter, tbNew)
        End If
    End If
    Return tbNew

Private Function GetFilterSpan(filter As String, ByVal tbNew As TextBlock) As Span
    Dim offset As Integer = tbNew.Text.ToLower().IndexOf(filter.ToLower()) + 1
    Try
        If offset > -1 Then
            Dim tpStart As TextPointer
            tpStart = tbNew.ContentStart.GetPositionAtOffset(offset)
            Dim tpEnd As TextPointer
            tpEnd = tbNew.ContentStart.GetPositionAtOffset(offset + filter.Length)
            If Not tpStart Is Nothing And Not tpEnd Is Nothing Then
                Dim result As New Span(tpStart, tpEnd)
                result = ApplySpanStrikeOutStyle(result)
                Return result
            End If
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return Nothing
    End Try
```

Comment: Hah, good old Joe Blogs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run your code with a watch set on tbNew.ContentEnd.Offset, you'll see the value change as the strikethroughs are applied. That illustrates why using

`Dim offset As Integer = tbNew.Text.ToLower().IndexOf(filter.ToLower()) + 1`

is not accurate - you're getting the IndexOf from the plain text, and then applying that offset to content which has text decorations applied.

From the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982916/how-to-find-a-textrange-in-richtextbox-between-two-textpointers), this should get you on your way.

```vb
  Public Function FormatFilteredName(mainFilter As String, subFilter As String) As TextBlock
        ' Dim tbNew As New TextBlock(New Run("111xxJoe Blogs09"))
        ' tbNew.Text = "111xxJoe Blogs09"
        ' tbNew.FontSize = 10
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(tbNew.Text) Then
            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(mainFilter) Then
                Dim mainFilterRange As TextRange = FindWordFromPosition(tbNew.ContentStart, mainFilter)
                If mainFilterRange IsNot Nothing Then
                    ApplyStrikeOutStyle(mainFilterRange)
                End If
            End If
            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(subFilter) Then
                Dim subFilterRange As TextRange = FindWordFromPosition(tbNew.ContentStart, subFilter)
                If subFilterRange IsNot Nothing Then
                    ApplyStrikeOutStyle(subFilterRange)
                End If
            End If
        End If
        Return tbNew
    End Function



    Private Function ApplyStrikeOutStyle(result As TextRange) As TextRange
        result.ApplyPropertyValue(Inline.TextDecorationsProperty,
                             TextDecorations.Strikethrough)
        Return result
    End Function


    Private Function FindWordFromPosition(position As TextPointer, word As String) As TextRange
        While position IsNot Nothing
            If position.GetPointerContext(LogicalDirection.Forward) = TextPointerContext.Text Then
                Dim textRun As String = position.GetTextInRun(LogicalDirection.Forward)

                ' Find the starting index of any substring that matches "word".
                Dim indexInRun As Integer = textRun.IndexOf(word)
                If indexInRun >= 0 Then
                    Dim start As TextPointer = position.GetPositionAtOffset(indexInRun)
                    Dim [end] As TextPointer = start.GetPositionAtOffset(word.Length)
                    Return New TextRange(start, [end])
                End If
            End If

            position = position.GetNextContextPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward)
        End While

        ' position will be null if "word" is not found.
        Return Nothing
    End Function
```

Comment: Thanks this does the trick!
Thought the plain text was likely causing the unpredictability but missed a couple of points in the implementation of getting the rich text index.
Appreciate your help :)

Comment: No worries - been a long time since I worked with WPF but scraped together what I could remember with Google and SO's help :)

Comment: Remember that this won't handle if there are multiple occurrences of your filter strings, too.